# WCF client not getting exception from service

Tags: wcf

I have a `WCF` service that has `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` set to true. When I test the service in `SOAP UI`, I can see that the response contains the error:

```
<ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel"    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
   <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
   <Message>Invalid Session Protocol</Message>
```

However, my client just picks up a very dull

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

message. So, there must be something I need to do in the client in order to enable it to read the response from the service.

My service config is this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <client>
      <endpoint 
          address="http://az00439/DRGDataService/StoreDataDotNet.svc" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" 
          contract="DRGDataService.IStoreDataDotNet" 
          name="DotNetClient" kind="" endpointConfiguration="">
          <identity>
              <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                                    x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName"/>
          </identity>
      </endpoint>
   </client>
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="basicBinding">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            </security>
         </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
         <binding name="webBinding">
             <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
             </security>
         </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
         <behavior name="AspNetAjaxBehavior">
            <enableWebScript/>
         </behavior>
         <behavior name="webEndpoint">
             <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" 
                      helpEnabled="true"/>
         </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="StoreDataBehaviour">
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true"  
                           httpsHelpPageUrl="true"/>
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  
                              multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
   <services>
       <service behaviorConfiguration="StoreDataBehaviour" name="DRGDataLibrary.StoreData">
          <host>
             <baseAddresses>
                 <add baseAddress="https://az00439/DRGDataService/StoreData.svc"/>
             </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint name="StoreDatawebHTTPBindingEndpoint"  
              address="" 
              behaviorConfiguration="AspNetAjaxBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" 
              contract="DRGDataLibrary.StoreData" />
   </service>
   <service name="DRGDataLibrary.StoreDataDotNet"
       behaviorConfiguration="StoreDataBehaviour" >
       <host>
          <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="https://az00439/DRGDataService/StoreDataDotNet.svc"/>
               <add baseAddress="http://az00439/DRGDataService/StoreDataDotNet.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
       </host>
       <endpoint name="StoreDataDotNetWebHttpEndpoint" 
           address="" 
           behaviorConfiguration="webEndpoint"
           binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding"  
           contract="DRGDataLibrary.IStoreDataDotNet" />

       <endpoint name="StoreDataDotNetBasicHttpEndpoint" 
           address="http://az00439/DRGDataService/StoreDataDotNet.svc" 
           behaviorConfiguration=""
           binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding" 
           contract="DRGDataLibrary.IStoreDataDotNet" />
       </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

(There's a fair bit going on in this config, because I'm using SSL and making JS calls to the service)

Thanks

Nick Wright

Answer (score 0):

What exception type are you catching? If it's just a non-generic `FaultException`, there's no way to get access to any fault-specific detail provided by the service.

When you enable `includeExceptionDetailInFaults`, it looks like WCF uses the [`ExceptionDetail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.exceptiondetail%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Data Contract to encode the information you're seeing in SoapUI, which means you should be able to get hold of it by catching `FaultException<ExceptionDetail>` and examining the exception's `Detail` property.

All that said, the [official recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedebugbehavior.includeexceptiondetailinfaults%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is to use `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` for debugging only, and [build better error-reporting mechanisms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg281715%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with custom Fault Contracts and `IErrorHandler` - so it's questionable whether your client should be relying on information in `ExceptionDetail` anyway.

Comment: hi - thanks for your answer. Haven't had chance to get back into this yet, but will try your suggestions when I do.